# Phaser rendering black screen depending on how I instantiate a shader

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

If I create a shader using `this.add.shader()`, I get the expected result (a blurred image rendered in my camera view), but if I create that same shader using `new Phaser.GameObjects.Shader()`, I get a black screen.

I made a small demo/example: https://codepen.io/alexandernst/pen/aboKepQ?editors=1010

Check lines 95 and 96. Commenting line 95 and uncommenting line 96 produces a black screen. What could be the issue?

Comment: I created an issue in Github: https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/4758